# Select rows from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I need to select different rows from a data frame and put them into their individual data frame.

My data frame has 7 variables: a country variable and 6 macro-level variables such as gdp, economic growth, depth etc..

I have 9 different countries in my data frame which means I have 9 rows and 7 columns.

Now I need to "select" 9 individual rows (one row for each country) in oder to have 9 different sub data frames that each consist just of one country and the values of its 6 macro-variables.

I tried the following command but it did not work:

```
df.country1 <- df %>%
  select(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5, variable6) %>%
  filter(country=="country1")
```

Could someone please help me with the correct command for my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Would you consider giving us a sample data set and an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

We can `split` by 'country' and then `select` those 'variable' to get a `list` of `data.frame`

```
library(dplyr)
lst <- df %>%
         split(.$country) %>%
         select_at(vars(starts_with("variable")))
```

But, if this is to do some calculations based on each 'country', instead of doing the `split`, use `group_by(country)`

---

It is better not to have individual objects in the global environment and all the operations can be done within the `list` object itself.  However, if the objects are really required, then use `list2env`

```
names(lst) <- paste0("df.", names(lst))
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

In the OP's code, it is not working, because after the `select` step, there are only 'variable' columns and no 'country' column to `filter` (assuming that it is not a grouped dataset).  The `filter` step should be before the `select`